# settings bundle interaction

Tags: iphone, ios4, settings, bundle

1. Is that possible to set slider (or another setting element) to disable state depending to current value of toggle switch specifier? Saw it in apple application settings (safari). Can I do it for my own?
2. How can I show current slider value in title value specifier?

Thanks a lot!